# Camera Follow Causing Player To Stutter Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently trying to make the camera follow the player smoothly. The script works fine but the problem is that this script is causing the player to stutter at a certain point. For example, if the player is at X:3, the player would stutter but then if the player was at X:-6, the player would stop stuttering. I'm 100% sure that this script is the problem because if I remove the script, the player stops stuttering.

Here is the camera follow script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraFollowing : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Transform target;

    [SerializeField]
    private Vector3 cameraOffset;

    [SerializeField]
    private float followSpeed = 10f;

    [SerializeField]
    private float xMin = 0f;

    private Vector3 velocity = Vector3.zero;

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 targetPos = target.position + cameraOffset;
        Vector3 clampedPos = new Vector3(Mathf.Clamp(targetPos.x, xMin, float.MaxValue), targetPos.y, targetPos.z);
        Vector3 smoothPos = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, clampedPos, ref velocity, followSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);

        transform.position = smoothPos;
    }
}
```

If you know the answer or possible causes please tell me, I'm trying to release, publish, etc, this game by the end of this year. Thanks! :D

Comment: PS - I'm quite new to c# and unity, so if you know the answer, can you please explain it, thanks!

Comment: The player stutters? That doesn’t make sense if the camera is  what the script is attached to. Is the camera the one that stutters? I don’t think you are modifying the player’s transform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By stutter I think you mean shake or tremble (not familiar with the stutter word).
I would try to adjust to the [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.SmoothDamp.html) example. Use `void Update()` or `LateUpdate()` instead of `FixedUpdate()`.

You may want to use `void LateUpdate()` if you want your game to be accurate. This method will be called after the input is detected, so it will react better. I believe that this is the better choice, because it will be more accurate than `Update()`.

I would also keep track of where in the scene the shake starts if its from a determined point on, and check for some misplaced collider near the position where the undesired shake starts.

Comment: Actually you could use `LateUpdate` so the camera is definitely moved after user Input was handled